# How do I visually format React button components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a basic calculator with React and am having trouble figuring out how to format the buttons in the typical format (ex: "0 . =" on the bottom row, '1 2 3 +' on on the next row up and so on..) with React and Bootstrap.

I have the functionality working but keep running into errors when I try to use a grid ( etc.). Any recommendations on how to approach this? (New to React)

```
    render() { 
        //object destructuring
        const { onReset, buttons, onPress } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <button
                    onClick={onReset}
                    className='btn btn-primary btn-sm m-2'
                    >
                        Reset
                </button>

                {buttons.map(button => (
                    
                    <Button 
                        key={button.id}
                        onPress={onPress}
                        button = {button} 
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Edit in response to @lucasvw 's comment:

I attempted to wrap the .map method in . 'button not defined' was the error.

```
    {
        <Container>
            <Row>
                buttons.map(button => (
                        
                    <Button 
                        key={button.id}
                        onPress={onPress}
                        button = {button} 
                    />
                ))
            </Row>
        </Container>
    }
```

I also attempted to build a for loop to spit on button out at a time. I don't have that code handy, but I believe it was a series of unexpected expression errors.

Comment: You say "keep running into errors when I try to use a grid". What errors? This has very little to do with React and very much to do with css (and bootstrap). Can you show us what you tried with a grid?

Comment: I would say use `<button>` instead then apply grid to them, why you would want to map on it.

Comment: @Digambernegi mapping a group of objects to components is very common in React

Comment: I tried @Digambernegi 's solution earlier. The issue with that is that it won't produce unique key ids. Each button as an id and value defined in my App.jsx. Perhaps I can play around with getting rid of that though

Comment: Can you tell us more about the error that you're facing in the post?

Comment: That code isn't giving me an error. That's it working but with each button on a separate line. Every way I've attempted to separate the buttons onto different lines such as the bottom line having buttons for '0' '.' '=' and the next line up being '1' '2' 3' '+' (like on an actual calculator) I run into errors. I'm wondering how to go about having multiple buttons on one line (or row) then another group of buttons on another.